# Can't find Swedish language pack for English FireFox 15

Tags: firefox, windows-8, language, localization

I can't seem to find information on installing a Swedish language package on my machine.

The language is not listed on [the Firefox website](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/language-tools/) and the hits on Google I got led nowhere (or, rather, to the said page). I have language support on the system (including the other browsers).

What am I missing?

Comment: [This forum post](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/922082) suggests a way to get a Swedish dictionary into Firefox, but it's not a full-blown language pack.

Comment: @AlEverett Could you kindly repost your comment as an answer? Also, please include those two links in the body so we'll have a nice piece of knowledge resolving the issue? [Link to the language files](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/dict-sv) and [link to the reference on how to install](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dictionaries#Installing_manually_to_the_application).

Comment: Sure thing. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Found at this forum](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/922082):

> There is this Swedish dictionary from the Open Office project.
>
> http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/dict-sv
>
> You will have to extract the two files (sv_SE.aff and sv_SE.dic) in the /dictionaries folder in that ZIP archive and install the dictionary manually by copying the files to the dictionary folder in the Firefox installation folder.
>
> See: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dictionaries#Installing_manually_to_the_application

Also

> The .oxt file is a ZIP archive and you can open that archive in a (ZIP) file manager and extract the sv_SE.aff and sv_SE.dic files in the dictionaries folder in that archive.
>
> You may need to rename the file and give it a .zip file extension.
>   Copy the sv_SE.aff and sv_SE.dic file to the dictionaries folder in the Firefox program folder (C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox)

Answer (score 3):

The [Firefox download page](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html) lists a Swedish version:

[image]

Comment: Humm, I guess I have a misconception about what language packs actually do in this context...

Comment: I'm only looking for language pack, so that I get spellcheck in Swedish. The rest of the system is English. It said so in my original post but was removed during some editing.

Comment: @Chamster - So put that information back.

Comment: @Ramhound It says so already in the subject. Looking for "Swedish language pack for..." not "Swedish version of..." but I can imagine that a trigger happy user won't notice the distinction. After all, it's a fairly unusual matter.

Answer (score 2):

The Language Pack Install Helper add-on allows you to install any language pack:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/language-pack-install-helpe/?src=api

Answer (score 1):

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/addons/3064/

Here you can find the dictionary.
Just click in the latest and agree to install it.