# Can't get non-english languages to work on FF25

Tags: firefox, language, language-pack

I've had this problem before and it was resolved [thanks to hints and suggestions](https://superuser.com/questions/480363/cant-find-swedish-language-pack-for-english-firefox-15). Now, I just got a new computer and the same problem occurs.

The root of the issue is that I'm using English Win7, English FF25 but still want to be able to switch between Swedish and English in the dialog boxes.

Right now, I only see US English, like so:

[image]

When I follow the link to adding more dictionaries, I can do so. Then, I can check that the stuff (language pack, language pack installer, IXP-file and whatever) are installed. Never the less, I still only get the English spell-check.

What do I do?

## EDIT

[image]

Comment: Is the Swedish language [added, and enabled in Windows?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Add-or-change-an-input-language)

Comment: Please see the edit. I've got that installed, as the second image shows.

Comment: Please check if this happens in a [new profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles). In the new profile please install [svensk_ordlista-1.49-tb+sm+fx.xpi](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/addons/3064/), [link](http://superuser.com/questions/480363/cant-find-swedish-language-pack-for-english-firefox-15/594640#594640). If the new profile is okay, you can delete this, open Firefox in the old profile, and [Reset Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems).